# XmlHttpRequest to JsonService failing

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, service, xmlhttprequest

I am having trouble with sending an XmlHttpRequest to a JsonService.
When I go to the link through google chrome it's working.
When I use this command for chrome (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrRX0.png) it is also working. But I need to get it to work without these steps ofcourse.
This is my XmlHttpRequest:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnSendEmail").click(function() {

            var message = new Model.Message();
            message.From = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
            message.Subject = "Contact Formulier: " + document.getElementById("txtSubject").value;
            message.Html = "Telefoon: " + document.getElementById("txtTelephone").value + "<br/>" +
                "Bedrijf: " + document.getElementById("txtCompany").value + "<br/><br/>" +
                "Bericht: " + "<br/>" +
                document.getElementById("txtMessage").value;
            message.Recipients = [];
            var recipient = new Model.Recipient();
            recipient.Email = "p.borgmans@mobileaccess.be";
            recipient.Name = "Pieter Borgmans";
            recipient.Type = "To";
            message.Recipients.push(recipient);

            var params = JSON.stringify(message);
            var url = "http://localhost:26294/JsonService.svc/Test";

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = function() {
                if (this.status === 200) {
                    var response = (this.responseText) ? JSON.parse(this.responseText) : this.responseText;
                    $("#lblSendMailMessage").text = response;
                } else {
                    $("#lblSendMailMessage").text = xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText;
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = function (onErrorArgs) {
                $("#lblSendMailMessage").text = "Error";
            };
            xhr.send();
        });
    });
```

Code in my service interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public partial interface IBusinessManager
{

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof (ServiceFault))]
    [WebGet(
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "Test")]
    string Test();
}
```

And I added this code in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS, TRACE, HEAD" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Anyone got an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does not work as expected and how should it work?

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, why are you using `XmlHttpRequest` directly? You can use [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and save yourself a lot of trouble, plus hook into its success/error handlers for easier debugging.

Comment: This is the error message that I am receiving: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:26294/JsonService.svc/Test. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

When I check my Network tab I can see that this is showing for my request:
Request URL:http://localhost:26294/JsonService.svc/Test
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:[::1]:26294

As you can see there is a error & onload hooked in. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the custom headers in the Global.asax file from my webservice instead of my web.config & it worked.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, TRACE, HEAD");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, Origin, Connection, User-Agent, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Content-Type");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```